# What exact rules does git / diff exactly follow to determine conflcts?

Tags: git, csv, diff

How **exactly** does `git` determine that there is a conflict between lines? What rules are followed to determine what types of differences constitute a conflict and which ones can be safely merged?

For a particular example, say we have two `csv` files. When would git conclude that two `csv` files that share records (i.e. rows) cannot be merged automatically?

For example, say both csv include the same common set of records, but one of them is **adding** entries, could this ever cause a conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the tool used for diff. **Normally** diffs compare lines. If one line is changed
on a revision and the same line is modified on another revision, if you try to merge them you'll have a conflict.

`diff` [is based on solving the longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm).

`diff` does not know a line was modified. It knows a line (or various lines)  was removed and
another one (or more than one) was inserted between two identical parts of file.

revision A:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

revision B:

```
a b c
d e a f
g h i
```

`$ diff A B`

will output that line `d e f` was removed
and line `d e a f` was inserted on file B
in comparison with file A between the identical
lines `a b c` and `g h i`.

If file A is modified into C:

```
a b c
c
d e b f
g h i
```

the diff will output that the same line was removed,
but lines `c` and `d e b f` were inserted.

Merging B and C, the conflict will not be only

```
d e a f
====
d e b f
```

but

```
d e a f
====
c
d e b f
```

So, in a short way, diff searches for identical blocks of lines.
If files were modified between these blocks on both files (and the modification
was not identical), there will be a conflict.

Comment: Thanks, but how does `git` (or GNU `diff` or `opendiff` for that matter) know that it is the **same** line?

Comment: I see. Thanks. I guess the question is how does `diff` (e.g. `GNU diff`) determine that two lines have enough content in common to be the same line?

Comment: Diff will "treat lines as the same" only if they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use your own plugin to handle conflicts in git if you don't like the way it's handling your conflicts.

However, check out this page for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28revision_control%29#Three-way_merge

Comment: This allows you to use a tool to deal with conflicts *after* they have been deemed conflicts.  It does not impact how Git automerges files.